# Removing duplicate words from an string array and writing to an output file

Tags: java

I have an assignment that requires me to take the words from an input.txt file and sort them by frequency and then write them to an output.txt file.

The problem I'm having is that once I find the frequency of each of the words from the input file, I have no idea how to remove the duplicates and how to keep them from being written to the output file.

Comment: Why do you put the strings into a StringBuilder just to split them, instead of just using an ArrayList or something like that?

Comment: My professor wanted us to use StringBuilder. I also wanted to do an ArrayList as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider that when your inner 'j' loop ends, your outer 'i' loop may proceed to go over the next occurrence of the *same* word. That's why you're seeing the same words output multiple times, with the count decreasing by one each time.

You can get closer by setting 'i' relative to 'j' when the 'j' loop ends. Alternatively, consider eliminating the 'j' loop, and compare tokens[i] to tokens[i-1].

After that, you still will not have sorted the output by word frequency. But you don't want us to do your homework.

I suggest using a Java IDE like Eclipse, and learning how to use the Java debugger.

Comment: I love you Joel. Simple solution for such a simple problem. Best answer!

Comment: And I'm definitely downloading Eclipse after this whole fiasco. I've been using crappy JGRASP this entire time.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the logic i will be using:

1. Create a class which will contain string value and count. Lets cal it StringVal. Equals and hashcode method in StringVal will not use count and will just use String value.
2. Use HashMap like: `Map<StringVal,int> strCount = new HashMap<StringVal,int>();`
3. Now go on reading and storing string in map. Add if it doesn't exist in map and increment count if it exists. [This removes duplicacy]
4. Now write a comparator which can sort StringVal based on count.

With this logic you can achieve whta you are looking for.

Comment: I'm really sorry but I'm not familiar with HashMap or TreeMap at all. I was thinking of something along the lines of storing my array of strings into a new temporary array of strings, then writing a loop to filter them by looking for duplication before writing them to the file.

Comment: @Daniel: tht would be very costly operation. A map will be right datastructure for your problem. I would suggest to read about it a little. Will be very helpful/

Answer (score 0):

Use each word as a key in a hashmap     each occurrence s a new key or increments integer.  Once done loop through the keys in a for each....

Answer (score -1):

Filter them first then sort them. like using an arraylist to store string and use loop to check whether the string is already at the arraylist and after filtering you can now sort them.

Comment: Basically arraylist can be used just to store strings, its just for basic and simplicity

Comment: but it will be very costly to check for duplicates in arraylist at each insertion, thts why i said wrong choice of data structure.